# How to extend or isolate a constant value in AngularJS when using modules?

Tags: angularjs, constants, modularity

To keep my code clean I'm in the habit of defining url's as constants in my AngularJs applications, looking like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);
myApp.constant('URL', {
    google: 'http://www.google.com',
    facebook: 'http://www.facebook.com'
});
```

Now, that works fine but I get into problems when I also define (and use) this constant in my module:

```
var myModule= angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.constant('URL', {
    twitter: 'http://www.twitter.com'
});
```

Because, now when I want to use the URL.twitter constant in a directive (inside my module) it is no longer available because the definition of the URL constant in 'myApp' has overriden the value. For example when I create a directive:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: function(URL){
            console.log(URL.twitter); // logs undefined when used within 'myApp'
        }
    };
});
```

See a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xiOGVWfJ4GupSvkTs0Ic?p=preview

Think of 'myModule' being a third-party module which I include in my project. If I accidentally use the same names for my constants, the whole thing is broken.

How to overcome this use case without having to use different names for the same purpose?

Comment: I read it like 5 times, but I still can't make sense to your question... Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @domokun Does it make more sense now? I added an example.

Comment: Considered making a URL service and injecting where needed?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, but I think I've spotted a couple of issues. Gimme 5 mins

Comment: I added a plunker example.

Comment: @mccainz I do not see what that is going to help with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question boils down to:

A third party module (that I didn't write) defines 'URL' as a constant.

I include this module as dependency in my app, and define URL too (without knowing that URL was already defined):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['thirdPartyModule']);
app.constant('URL', { twitter: 'www.twitter.com'});
```

All of a sudden, the app breaks and stops working.

How does one avoid this pitfall?

Answer:

You can use angular's injector to determine if the constant is already defined:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['thirdPartyModule']);
var injector = angular.injector(),
    url = injector.has('URL') ? injector.get('URL') : {};
```

The above code will guarantee that an object will be returned - either the URL defined in a third party module, or an empty object literal, if it is not defined.

Then, you can extend the 'URL' as follows:

```
angular.extend(url, { twitter: 'www.twitter.com' });
```

*Word of Caution:*

This will work if URL was previously undefined or defined in a third-party module as an object literal. This will not work if URL was previously defined as a primitive (ie. string).

Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to guard against this scenario in a clean way.  I would recommend not overriding previously defined constants at all, and relying on naming convention to make your injectables unique.  For example, for your constants, services, providers and factories, use a unique prefix that reduces the likelihood of naming collisions:

```
var app = angular.module('tgApp', ['thirdPartyModule']);
app.constant('tgURL', { ... });
```

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. I already thought of an extend solution but could not figure out a (clean) way to do it. The injector solution is also not 'clean' in my opinion but...it is a solution. I think I'll have to go with the naming convention then.

Comment: That might be the better way to go. Angular has one injector per app even with multiple dependencies, and there's currently way to namespace them.  I hope angular provides some namespace feature in the future. For example, it would be great if you do: app.controller($scope, app.URL) where 'app' was the name of your module. If 'app' was not prefixed, then it would return the last injected definition of URL.

Answer (score 1):

I Realize this is an old question but I didn't see this answer provided.  I just spent a few hours banging my head against the desk on the very same issue the OP described.  I have quite a few jQuery widgets I am converting to angular.  These are essentially third-party modules that will be used across several sites.  I solved this issue by using a provider for each module.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.provider('myModuleProvider', function() {
    this.$get = [function() {
        return {
            twitter: 'http://www.twitter.com',
        };
    }]
})

myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: function(myModuleProvider) {
            var URL = myModuleProvider;
            console.log(URL.twitter);
        }
    }
})
```

My example does make full use of providers but the nice thing is they can be configurable.  So if I have "options" I want to expose they can be configured via the angular.config() function on the module that myModule is being injected in to.

Comment: Good alternative approah.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an angular module named **myApp**, which depends on the module **myModule**.
Then you add some costants to the module **myApp**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);
myApp.constant('URL', {
    google: 'http://www.google.com',
    facebook: 'http://www.facebook.com'
});
```

Then you are creating **myModule** and adding the twitter constant to it. That is:
  - google and facebook are bound to **myApp**
  - twitter is bound to **myModule**

Then, you're injecting URL into a directive, trying to recover the twitter URL.
This heavily depends on what is before the `myModule.directive` line.

Using:  `var myModule = angular.module('myModule')` you should find the ***twitter*** constant
Using:  `var myModule = angular.module('myApp')` you should find the ***google*** and ***facebook*** constant

---

I usually use a clearer (in my opinion) approach:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp')
myApp.factory('appConstants', function() {
    return {
        facebook: "www.facebook.com",
        google: "www.google.com",
        twitter: "www.twitter.com"
    }   
})
```

And then you just inject it whenever you need it and use it like: `appConstants.facebook`

What do you think about it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not solve the problem. Here is modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gJUYb2gzj2NMaBwOxaz7. As you can see It still overrides the values. The whole issue is that I want the constants to have the same same, being isolated within the module. As a sidenote I think we should use the .constants option angular provides for this stuff.

Comment: Think of myModule being a third-party module which I include in my project. If I accidentally use the same names for my constants, the whole thing is broken.

Comment: You just changed names, but you're referring to the wrong module!
If you try to print (in your Plunkr) `constants.google`, it works

Comment: You are creating two different entities, and trying to use the one you have no visibility about.

The module created inside 'myApp' are isolated from the one in 'myModule'

Comment: I know...but i'm not trying to access the constants from myApp in myModule. I'm just trying to access the constant (twitter) from 'myModule' in 'myModule' but only I'm using the directive within 'myApp'. :)

Comment: I think the question is hierarchically trivial. Referring to your plunkr: **plunker** is your main module, the app, which depends on **myModule**, which is a sort of children to **plunker**.

When you inject **constants** in your directive, you're injecting **plunker.constants**, not **myModule.constants**. I don't think it exist a way to do what you would like to, and to be honest, I still don't get why you would want to do it.

Comment: I know that I'm injecting plunker.constants. But don't you agree that it is weird that this effects my child module which can be something I just use from a third-party resource. This is a real world use case right?